# Should I worry about fuel pump noises after a filter and injector change?

Tags: vw, fuel-system, fuel-pump

I recently fixed a starting problem with my 2007 VW Rabbit. I ended up replacing both the fuel filter and fuel injectors. After I was done, per the manuals directions, I flushed as much air as I could out of the fuel rail. Unlike the manual I did this by pressurizing the system using the driver side door which triggers the fuel pump. I probably got 3 to 4 cups of fuel out before the air was gone.

I noticed after a while though when purging the air that the fuel pump started making a higher pitch sound that I'd never heard from it. Now, after driving for about 5 miles, it still makes this higher pitch whine when pressurizing prior to starting via the front door trigger.

The car runs and starts great now, but I worry that something is going wrong with the fuel pump due to something I did. Perhaps I purged the air from fuel rail, but something is left in the pump motor? Is this something to worry about or will it resolve itself?

Answer (score 0):

Two rules of thumb:

- If it makes an unusual noise, it is going bad.
- Issues don't go away, they worsen if left unresolved.

It could be that there is some freak case where there is something inside the fuel pump and the issue will cure itself over time. However, this is the exception.

The most likely case is that the pump ran dry long enough to cause damages and you now have a worn bearing inside the pump. A fuel pump is considered non-repairable (IMHO), so be prepared to replace it.

Comment: So in general I agree with this. The thing is, I was running the pump manually for about a total of 8 seconds and heard it go from good to bad. My thought was maybe it was the sound of it running with air still in it. I guess I'll find out soon if its going bad.